# Only the content of org.springframework.data.domain.Page is displayed, without metadata

Tags: java, xml, rest, cxfrs

I have created the rest controller using spring-boot and apache cxf-rs, which returns the Page (`org.springframework.data.domain.Page`) with the entities. My problem is that Page in xml formal returns only Content with entities, without metadata (pageable, sort...). In json format all works fine - Page is dysplayed Content and metadata.

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.jaxb.PageAdapter;

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PageAdapter.class)
    Page<Monitor> getAllMonitors(@PathParam("page") int page, 
        @PathParam("size") int size){
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

In config class I have a Bean for XML, provided by cxf-rs:

```
    @Bean
    public JAXBElementProvider jaxbElementProvider(){
        JAXBElementProvider jaxbElementProvider = new JAXBElementProvider();
        jaxbElementProvider.setSingleJaxbContext(true);
        jaxbElementProvider.setExtraClass(new Class[] {Monitor.class});
        return jaxbElementProvider;
    }
```

I expect to see the page like this:

```
<sd:page xmlns:sd="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jaxb" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <content>
    <Monitor>
    ... content
    </Monitor>
  </content>
  <pageable>
  ...
  </pageable>
  <sort>
  ...
  </sort>
  <totalElements>...</totalElements>
  <numberOfElements>...</numberOfElements>
</sd:page>
```

But I receive page only with content:

```
<sd:page xmlns:sd="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jaxb" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <content>
    <Monitor>
    ... content
    </Monitor>
  </content>
</sd:page>
```

What should I do for displaying full Page in xml format?
Thanks for any help!